# Inspecting Server-Sent Events

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

What is the best way to inspect Server-Sent Events when the browser receives them. I've only seen implementations where you simply do `console.log(e)`, but that assumes your data is correct.

Is there a way to look at Server-Sent Events as you do with a 'View Source' type of inspection without using console.log?

Comment: So you want to listen to the HTTP traffic? There are a few tools to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to a Server Sent Event stream using curl if you want to watch the raw data coming in with no parsing.

```
curl --no-buffer http://my.app/event_stream/
```

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) will log all sent events and make them inspectable on real time.